# Error with long descriptions in Youtube Video Upload through Youtube API

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to upload a video to youtube through youtube direct upload. It works fine. And then I created a video with a very long description. Then I'm getting the following error;

com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error><domain>yt:validation</domain><code>too_long</code><location type='xpath'>media:group/media:description/text()</location></error></errors>
```

I wonder whether it's due to the length of the description or could that be due to some other reason?

Given below is my Code

```
private String uploadVideo(YouTubeService service, String videoLocation,String mimeType,String title) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException, ServiceException, IOException {
    String id = "";
    File videoFile = new File(videoLocation);
    if (!videoFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, that video doesn't exist.");

    }
    String videoTitle = title;
    VideoEntry newEntry = new VideoEntry();
    YouTubeMediaGroup mg = newEntry.getOrCreateMediaGroup();
    mg.setTitle(new MediaTitle());
    mg.getTitle().setPlainTextContent(videoTitle);
    mg.setKeywords(new MediaKeywords());
    mg.getKeywords().addKeyword("yt:crop=16:9");
    mg.setDescription(new MediaDescription());
    mg.getDescription().setHtmlContent(attributionDocument);
    mg.setPrivate(true);
    mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.CATEGORY_SCHEME, "Tech"));


    MediaFileSource ms = new MediaFileSource(videoFile, "video/quicktime");
    newEntry.setMediaSource(ms);

    String uploadUrl =
      "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";

    VideoEntry createdEntry = service.insert(new URL(uploadUrl), newEntry);
    id =createdEntry.getId();
    return id;

    }
```

I'll be really grateful if someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response XML says "too_long" about "media:group/media:description/text()".  That's pretty conclusive to me.

Use a shorter description and the problem should go away.

---

FWIW, [this link](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_media%3adescription) says what the `media:description` is supposed to contain, and it mentions that there are size limits.

Comment: Thanx, you confirmed my doubt. I wonder whether there's a way to deal with these long descriptions, because I use these descriptions to give credit to the owners of images in my video. This way I can not really publish a video with many images :(